# Show two columns (one text, one inline tikZ math) appearing simultaneously one item at a time

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, itemize, two-column, overlays

In a presentation, I am trying to show four ideas in a sequential manner. I've split my frame into two columns: the left column shows the text, the right shows the math. I want to display the columns one item at a time, simultaneously in both columns. I tried the following approach, but what's happening is that the inline math (which used to be inline) is no longer on the same row as the text. Can someone please help? Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns, positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes,
                tikzmark
                }
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
%\usepackage{fourier,erewhon}
%\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}


\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
% modifications of 
% \tikzset{
%     invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
%     visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
% }
% from overlay-beamer-styles

\tikzset{sort of visible/.style={opacity=0.3,text opacity=0.3},
fully visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{sort of visible}},}
\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}


\begin{frame}{Step 2: (Approximate) Feasibility Condition as Potential}
\tikzset{optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = myblue,
            thick,
            fill= myyellow,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center}}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Goal
            \item<2-> Instead, track
            \item<3-> Invariant 
            \item<4-> Termination at 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.66\linewidth}%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> \raisebox{1 ex}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,thick]
\draw
node [baseline, style=optimization problem, fully visible on = <1>] {$ \lambda_{\textup{max}}(N) \leq (1+\epsilon) \lambda_{\textup{min}}(M).$};
\end{tikzpicture}} 
            \item<2-> \raisebox{.5 ex}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,thick]
\draw
node [baseline, style=optimization problem] {$ (1-\epsilon) \log f \exp(N)  + \log f \exp(-M).$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
            \item<3-> \raisebox{.5 ex}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,thick]
\draw
node [baseline, style=optimization problem] {$g \leq \log n$};
\end{tikzpicture}}
            \item<4-> \raisebox{.5 ex}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,thick]
\draw
node [baseline, style=optimization problem] {$\lambda_{\textup{min}}(M)\geq \frac{\log n}{\epsilon}$};
\end{tikzpicture}} 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}  

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The proposal here is to use the built-in columns of beamer, and to synchronize them in a rather brutal yet working way.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns, positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes,
                tikzmark
                }
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
% modifications of 
% \tikzset{
%     invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
%     visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
% }
% from overlay-beamer-styles

\tikzset{sort of visible/.style={opacity=0.3,text opacity=0.3},
fully visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{sort of visible}},}

\newcommand<>{\SyncCols}[3][0.3\linewidth]{\begin{columns}
\begin{column}{#1}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \vphantom{#3}#2
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\begin{column}{\dimexpr\linewidth-#1-0.02\linewidth}
\begin{itemize}
 \item \vphantom{#2}#3
\end{itemize}
\end{column}
\end{columns}}

\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}


\begin{frame}{Step 2: (Approximate) Feasibility Condition as Potential}
\tikzset{optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = myblue,
            thick,
            fill= myyellow,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center}}

\uncover<1->{\SyncCols{Goal}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
\node[style=optimization problem, fully visible on = <1>](X){%
$ \lambda_{\textup{max}}(N) \leq (1+\epsilon) \lambda_{\textup{min}}(M)$.};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
%
\uncover<2->{\SyncCols{Instead, track}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
\node[style=optimization problem, fully visible on = <2>](X){%
$(1-\varepsilon) \log f \exp(N)  + \log f \exp(-M)$.};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
%
\uncover<3->{\SyncCols{Invariant}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
\node[style=optimization problem, fully visible on = <3>](X){%
$g \leq \log n$.};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
%
\uncover<4->{\SyncCols{Termination at}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(X.base)}]
\node[style=optimization problem, fully visible on = <4>](X){%
$\lambda_{\textup{min}}(M)\geq \frac{\log n}{\varepsilon}$.};
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I could imagine that a perhaps better way to do this here is to use a raster of `tcolorbox`, and also do the boxes with `tcolorbox`. Alternatively you could use the nodes as above but put them in a matrix of `tikz` with the left column being filled by the texts.

In fact, with a matrix one can do funny little things with the count `\pgfmatrixcurrentrow`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Step 2: (Approximate) Feasibility Condition as Potential}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = myblue,
            thick,
            fill= myyellow,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center},
            pics/trian/.style={code={\fill[blue!80!black] 
            (0,0) -- (150:1ex) -- (210:1ex) --cycle;}}]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
    nodes={anchor=west,
    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->,},
    column 2/.style={nodes={optimization problem,
    alt=<\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>{}{opacity=0.3,text opacity=0.3},
    alt=<-\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1>{opacity=0,text opacity=0}{},
    }}](M){
Goal & $ \lambda_{\textup{max}}(N) \leq (1+\varepsilon)
\lambda_{\textup{min}}(M)$\\
Instead, track & $(1-\varepsilon) \log f \exp(N)  + \log f \exp(-M)$\\
Invariant & $g \leq \log n$\\
Termination at & 
$\lambda_{\textup{min}}(M)\geq \frac{\log n}{\varepsilon}$\\
};          

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, there is no need to put in overlay specifications at all. Everything is done automatrixally.

Of course, one can add the triangles automatrixally, too, if needed.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,overlay-beamer-styles}

\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
\frametitle{Step 2: (Approximate) Feasibility Condition as Potential}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = myblue,
            thick,
            fill= myyellow,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center},
            pics/trian/.style={code={\fill[blue!80!black] 
            (0,0) -- (150:1ex) -- (210:1ex) --cycle;}}]

\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={anchor=west,
    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->},
    every odd column/.style={execute at begin node={\textcolor{blue!80!black}{$\blacktriangleright$}}},
    column 2/.style={column sep=1em},
    column 4/.style={nodes={optimization problem,
    alt=<\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>{}{opacity=0.3,text opacity=0.3},
    alt=<-\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1>{opacity=0,text opacity=0}{},
    }}](M){
&Goal & &$ \lambda_{\textup{max}}(N) \leq (1+\varepsilon)
\lambda_{\textup{min}}(M)$\\
&Instead, track & &$(1-\varepsilon) \log f \exp(N)  + \log f \exp(-M)$\\
&Invariant & &$g \leq \log n$\\
&Termination at & &
$\lambda_{\textup{min}}(M)\geq \frac{\log n}{\varepsilon}$\\
};          
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my goodness you are unstoppable! I was just going to ask you a question on the "automatrix" (hah!) slides, when you posted the triangles. So, regarding the second solution (matrix, no triangles), can you explain your line "\matrix[matrix of nodes,row sep=1em,column sep=1em,
    nodes={anchor=west,
    visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->,},
    column 2/.style={nodes={optimization problem,
    alt=<\pgfmatrixcurrentrow>{}{opacity=0.3,text opacity=0.3},
    alt=<-\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1>{opacity=0,text opacity=0}{},
    }}]" Specifically, why do we need that last option?

Comment: @lazulikid There are three cases: current overlay is smaller than the current row, equal, or larger. In the first case the node should be invisible, in the second fully visible and in the third transparent. However, `alt` only distinguishes two cases, so we need two `alt`s. This way of doing that is certainly not unique, but it works.

Comment: Thank you! From your comment, it appears that "overlay" is a number that is used to index a node that we want to point at in some way. Is this an accurate understanding of the concept? Further, is your option "visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->" what makes nodes invisible BEFORE the overlay is on them? Also, why do we need "\the" before \pgfmatrixcurrentrow?

Comment: @lazulikid Yes, I should have specified. An overlay in this context means the counter you use e.g. in `\only<{overlay}>`. And yes, `visible on=<\the\pgfmatrixcurrentrow->` does precisely what you are saying.

Comment: Sorry, last question, I hope! I still don't understand "    alt=<-\the\numexpr\pgfmatrixcurrentrow-1>{opacity=0,text opacity=0", since you already gave a command right before to specify the current overlay row to be dimmed out. Since lower the opacity, the more "clouded" the text/image is, it seems to me that the dimming option is being decsribed twice?

Comment: @lazulikid Yes, this is a bit tricky. It is necessary because of the order Ti*k*Z looks at the pgf keys. Always the one that gets applied last can overrule the previous ones. One can always find out the order by doing an experiment (or adding some `/utils/exec=\typeout{I am doing this now}` to debug), or by looking at the source code.

Comment: Hi @Schrödinger's cat, I have a follow-up question about this solution if it's ok. I want to create a slide with a similar matrix like the above, but the entire matrix appears (in the same manner with overlays as in the above solution) after some other elements on the slide (ie., after some \pause commands). In this case, the \pgfmatrixcurrentrow command causes the right hand side columns to remain at opacity = 0.3 throughout. How do I change this, so that the above effect works when the matrix comes after some pauses in the slide?

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that the `minipage` is a bit too narrow, so the `tikzpicture` gets pushed to the next line. Make it `0.67\textwidth` wide, and it looks better.

To get better vertical alignment on the line, remove all the `\raisebox`es, give the nodes a name like `a`, and set `baseline=(a.base)` in the `tikzpicture` options.

[image]

The items in the two lists are not vertically aligned, because the lines are of different height, do you want them aligned?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
%  \usetheme{default}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
%  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
%  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta, 
                backgrounds,
                calc,
                decorations.pathmorphing,
                patterns, positioning, 
                quotes,
                shapes,
                tikzmark
                }
\usetikzlibrary{overlay-beamer-styles}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{raster}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\usepackage{makecell} %for the thead command to break up header
%\usepackage{fourier,erewhon}
%\usepackage{amssymb, amsbsy}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage[x11names, table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}


\definecolor{myorange}{rgb}{.98, .59, .01}
\definecolor{myyellow}{rgb}{1, .78, .33}
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{.18, .63, .78}
% modifications of 
% \tikzset{
%     invisible/.style={opacity=0,text opacity=0},
%     visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{invisible}},
% }
% from overlay-beamer-styles

\tikzset{sort of visible/.style={opacity=0.3,text opacity=0.3},
fully visible on/.style={alt=#1{}{sort of visible}},}
\begin{document}

\section{Problem Setup, History, \& Our Result: A Snapshot}


\begin{frame}{Step 2: (Approximate) Feasibility Condition as Potential}
\tikzset{optimization problem/.style = {%
            rounded corners, 
            draw = myblue,
            thick,
            fill= myyellow,
            inner ysep=5pt,
            inner xsep=5pt,
            align = center}}

\begin{minipage}[t]{0.30\linewidth}
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> Goal
            \item<2-> Instead, track
            \item<3-> Invariant 
            \item<4-> Termination at 
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.67\linewidth}%
        \begin{itemize}
            \item<1-> \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base),thick]
\node [style=optimization problem, fully visible on = <1>] (a) {$ \lambda_{\textup{max}}(N) \leq (1+\epsilon) \lambda_{\textup{min}}(M).$};
\end{tikzpicture}
            \item<2-> \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base),thick]
\node [style=optimization problem] (a) {$ (1-\epsilon) \log f \exp(N)  + \log f \exp(-M).$};
\end{tikzpicture}
            \item<3-> \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base),thick]
\node [style=optimization problem] (a) {$g \leq \log n$};
\end{tikzpicture}
            \item<4-> \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(a.base),thick]
\node [style=optimization problem] (a) {$\lambda_{\textup{min}}(M)\geq \frac{\log n}{\epsilon}$};
\end{tikzpicture}
        \end{itemize}
    \end{minipage}  
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution and time, @Torbjorn T. I did indeed require alignment. I accepted Schrodinger's cat's response, because it satisfied this requirement.